# How to get dynamic hidden id value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In html, I have used hidden fields with dynamic ids.

```
<a><input type="hidden" name="edit_hid" id="edit_'+id+'" value="123" />something 1</a>

<a><input type="hidden" name="edit_hid" id="edit_'+id+'" value="456" />something 2</a>

<a><input type="hidden" name="edit_hid" id="edit_'+id+'" value="789" />something 3</a>
```

Here I am getting the id of the above hidden element in jquery.

```
var hiddenID = $('input[name$="edit_hid"]').attr('id');
alert(hiddenID );
```

Whenever I click the hyperlink something 1, something 2, something 3, I am always getting the id as `edit_0`

How can I get the dynamic id for each hyperlink? so that I can get the value of those dynamic ids.

Comment: ? What you want to achive? What is that `edit_'+id+'`?

Comment: but in console, I am seeing the id value is incrementing. But when I get that id, it is not incrementing

Comment: Are those `id`s sequentials? `edit_1` `edit_2`, ...? If so, what's the point of having to get each individual id? You'd already know they are sequential

Comment: What's your ultimate goal in getting those ids? It's highly possible that you can achieve what you want without having to get those particular id...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use `:hidden` in jquery selector:

```js
$("a").on("click", function(){
    alert($(":hidden", this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a><input type="hidden" name="edit_hid" id="edit_'+id+'" value="123" />something 1</a>

<a><input type="hidden" name="edit_hid" id="edit_'+id+'" value="456" />something 2</a>

<a><input type="hidden" name="edit_hid" id="edit_'+id+'" value="789" />something 3</a>
```

Comment: Super! Working like a charm! This is what I m expecting

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this might work, could you be more clear, how were these link dynamically aadded, this may effect how this should work?

```
<script>
     $(function(){
       $(".hidden").click(function(){
         var a = $(this).attr("id");
       alert(a);
       });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: I need to specify this particular hidden id..not for all hidden type inputs.. cant click if it is hidden

Comment: What do you mean this particular id?

Comment: When or how do you want to get them? It needs to be on some sort of event? (Page load, click, mouse over, the click of another button)

Answer (score 0):

you are using `$('input[name$="edit_hid"]')` that returns a collection (array)

when you take `attr('id')` it will return the first `[0]` (id=0)

so you should use

```
var a=$('input[name$="edit_hid"]')[0].attr('id');
var b=$('input[name$="edit_hid"]')[1].attr('id');
var c=$('input[name$="edit_hid"]')[2].attr('id');
```

check for length property of the collection `$('input[name$="edit_hid"]').length` (it should be 3)

I think you don't need click function over a hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var hiddenID;
      $('input').live("focus", function() {
        hiddenID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(hiddenID );
        });
   });
```

`focus will binds only to elements that exist at the time it's called.

`live()` binds a function to an event for all existing elements, and any that are added to the DOM later.

Hope it will help you :)